# Submit Ration Button Value to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i have created a Form in my app. There is 3 things Mobile , Amount and `Radio Button` with 2 values (Male and Female) . when i press the submit `Button` Mobile and Amount save to `Database` But `RadioButton` values doesn't save .But when i double press on the `Radiobutton` its save the vale . I want the it will save when submit button is pressed.

Here is the code :

```
  private void Submit() {
            String Mobile = mobile.getText().toString().trim();
            String Amount = amount.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Mobile)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Mobile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Amount)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Amount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            demoRef.push().child("Mobile").setValue(Mobile);
            demoRef.push().child("Amount").setValue(Amount);

            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
                    switch (i){
                        case R.id.male:
                            demoRef.push().child("Method").setValue("Male");
                            break;
                        case R.id.female:
                            demoRef.push().child("Method").setValue("Female");
                            break;

                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below. I am adding a sample code. 
1.create a variable to store `gender` value which you will get from radio button and then set the listener to radioGroup in `onCreate()`.
2. Modify the `Submit()` method as shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// add this variable to hold gender value.
private String gender = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // your all other code which is already inside onCreate();
    ....
    // [EDIT BEGIN]
    RadioButton genderBtn=(RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    gender = genderBtn.getText().toString();
    // [EDIT END]
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
                switch (i){
                    case R.id.male:
                        gender = "Male";
                        break;
                    case R.id.female:
                        gender = "Female";
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
}


 // Modify submit method like below.
  private void Submit() {

        String Mobile = mobile.getText().toString().trim();
        String Amount = amount.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Mobile)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Mobile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Amount)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Amount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        demoRef.push().child("Mobile").setValue(Mobile);
        demoRef.push().child("Amount").setValue(Amount);
        demoRef.push().child("Method").setValue(gender);

}
```

Comment: I have facing a problem.  When my activity starts one Radiobutton checks auto.  But the value not saves. how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
    private void Submit() {
        String Mobile = mobile.getText().toString().trim();
        String Amount = amount.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Mobile)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Mobile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Amount)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Amount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        demoRef.push().child("Mobile").setValue(Mobile);
        demoRef.push().child("Amount").setValue(Amount);
        switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
             case R.id.male:
                 demoRef.push().child("Method").setValue("Male");
                     break;
             case R.id.female:
                 demoRef.push().child("Method").setValue("Female");
                     break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code while submit

```
public void onClick(View arg0) { 
 int selected=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton genderBtn=(RadioButton) findViewById(selected);
                String gender = genderBtn.getText().toString();
}
```